# Why doesn't Workbox use cache for offline use?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm using [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox).

I want to cache files from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net` so I add this to `service-worker.js`:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/.*'), new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({}), 'GET');
```

For the first time, I open the app, and I can see that my app is sent request to `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?v=4.9.95`.

The second time I hit refresh I can see it retrieve from service worker in network.

But when I do offline mode and hit refresh I got 404.

Why? what can I do to add to cache in the right way?

I do [exactly like say in docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/common-recipes) and in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1563) but not works ether.

My full code:

```
console.log('in pwa');

workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true,
});

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});


// The precaching code provided by Workbox. You don't need to change this part.
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);

console.log({ __precacheManifest: self.__precacheManifest });
// workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings()
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});


workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('https://fonts.(?:googleapis|gstatic).com/(.*)'),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'google-fonts',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 30,
      }),
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
        statuses: [0, 200]
      }),
    ],
  }),
);


workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/(.*)'),
  new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'jsdelivr-fonts',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 30,
      }),
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
        statuses: [0, 200]
      }),
    ],
  }),
);
// https://cdn.jsdelivr.net
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL('/index.html'));
```

NO cache sections (for google-fonts and jsdelivr-fonts) create:

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I remove completely the service worker, and I open the app, still I don't have the cache section. after I hit refresh - I Have!

How to do it when the service worker is install? and not activate?

Comment: Which request leads to a 404? The request for your HTML, or for the web font? And a 404 indicates that the network request was made, but the server responded with a 404 error code. Is that what you're actually seeing while offline?